# Spring Application Context Initialization

Tags: spring, initialization

In my Spring Application, at the time of context Initialization. The DB is not available, it will come up after some time (Due to DB redundancy). In this scenario, my spring application initialization should be delayed or the application should do retry for DB connectivity. How to achieve the same via Spring.

Srirama.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest investigating the [`ApplicationContextInitializer`](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/). It is meant to be used for setting up your context before most of the magic of spring initialization happens.

I'm not sure if it is designed for your use case, but no beans are initialized when the `initialize` method is called during startup.

The example provided in the link deals with properties, but I see no reason why you should not create your own *manually created* connection and wait for it's readiness.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

My application is initialized by means of C3P0. Here C3P0, is trying to reconnect to DB only for 30 times (the default configuration for acquireRetryAttempts) and after that it is saying failed to create the application beans.

Changed the configuration for acquireRetryAttempts to -1, so that C3P0 is retrying indefinitely till the DB connection is successful. Basically my app. initialization should be delayed till the DB comes up.

Srirama.